How do I parse TransactionInstruction in new web3.js?
I want to parse the new SetLoadedAccountDataSizeLimit ComputeBudget instruction in the Solana Explorer, but this only seems to be available in @solana-program/compute-budget, which requires the new web3.js library package.
Right now I'm parsing it via
let ix: TransactionInstruction; // old web3.js type

const type = identifyComputeBudgetInstruction(ix);

switch (type) {
    /* ... */
    case ComputeBudgetInstruction.SetLoadedAccountsDataSizeLimit: {
        const {
          data: { units, additionalFee },
        } = parseRequestUnitsInstruction({
          ...ix,
          programAddress: address(ix.programId.toBase58()),
        });
        /* ... */
    }
}

Is this the canonical way to convert legacy web3.js TransactionInstructions into IInstruction (what @solana-program/compute-budget seems to expect) ?

The legacy TransactionInstruction type has this shape:
{
    data: Buffer;
    keys: Array<{isSigner: boolean, isWritable: boolean, pubkey: PublicKey}>;
    programId: PublicKey;
}

The new IInstruction type has this shape:
{
    readonly accounts?: Array<{
        readonly address: Address;
        readonly role: AccountRole;
    }>;
    readonly data?: Uint8Array;
    readonly programAddress: Address;
}

The parseRequestUnitsInstruction function works in your example because it only cares about the data and programAddress fields.
If you are interested, we would be happy to review a PR to @solana/compat that adds a fromLegacyTransactionInstruction function to convert the legacy shape to the modern one.
